# Download file using terminal to local directory

Tags: scp

I m trying to download a file but can't seem to get it right.

```
scp root@ipaddress:oo_db_bck_2_aug.sql /home
```

If I try to set the path to /home/username/Desktop the username folder doesn't exist. Just leaving a / showed activity but I can't find the file.

```
oo_db_bck_2_aug.sql                                 100%  189KB 189.0KB/s   00:00
```

I know it's a bit dumb ... but how do I set the path to my Desktop. I can access my desktop like so: /home/username/Desktop just not when using `scp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scp the `oo_db_bck_2_aug.sql` file to the user folder `~`

```
scp root@ipaddress:/path/to/oo_db_bck_2_aug.sql ~
```

If you don't know the absolute path to `oo_db_bck_2_aug.sql`, just ssh to that ip address and run

```
readlink -f oo_db_bck_2_aug.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put an absolute path for the file on the remote host like so:

```
root@ipaddress:/path/to/file
```